# Play a file from the raw folder using Android mediaPlayer, using its resourceId

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In Android, I can use [MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.myFileName)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context,%20int)) to create an instance of the `mediaPlayer`, using a resource from the `raw/` folder, and I can then use [.start()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#start()) to get that file to play. Later, I can use the various signatures for [.setDataSource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String)) to change the file that I want to play.

I can obtain the resourceId for a given file in the `raw/` folder, using:

```
int resourceId = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("myFileName", "raw", activity.getPackageName());
```

Is it possible to use this integer resourceId to start playing that file instead of the current one? Or do I have to determine the full path to the file `res/raw/myFileName.mid` in order to change the track?

I am hoping that the solution will be something like this, with a real method instead of my invented `equivalentToSetDataSourceUsingAResourceId()` method name.

```
Resources resources = activity.getResources();
String packageName = activity.getPackageName();

int white = resources.getIdentifier("white", "raw", packageName);
int black = resources.getIdentifier("black", "raw", packageName);
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(activity, white);

mediaPlayer.start();
// ... and some time later...

mediaPlayer.reset();
mediaPlayer.equivalentToSetDataSourceUsingAResourceId(black);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

An alternative would be to destroy the current `mediaPlayer` instance and create a new one each time the sound file needs to change:

```
if (mediaPlayer != null) {
  mediaPlayer.stop();
  mediaPlayer.release();
  mediaPlayer = null;
}

mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(activity, black);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

This does not seem elegant to me.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MediaPlayer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) `setDataSource` API's allowed only on fresh instance (IDLE state) of MediaPlayer. Which means you have to `release()` and recreate MediaPlayer from scratch if you wanna use only one instance at time.

Try do like this. Just pass id of your raw resource:

mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.whatever);